# Can a polynomial have a lower bound if every starting coefficient is a positive integer?

Tags: polynomials, upper-lower-bounds

If I have a function with all positive integer for the coefficients, is there a way to have a lower bound? Zero isn't an option, because I've done the rational root theorem and found all possible roots. If you need, I can provide the function and its list of possible roots below:

$70x^{4}+163x^{3}+109x^{2}+37x+6$

$±1, ±1/2, ±1/5, ±1/7, ±1/10, ±1/14, ±1/35, ±1/70,$
$±2, ±2/5, ±2/7, ±2/35,$
$±3, ±3/2, ±3/5, ±3/7, ±3/10, ±3/14, ±3/35, ±3/70,$
$±6, ±6/5, ±6/7, ±6/35$

Comment: I am not sure the particular roots (if any) of the polynomial are so important for your question. I think you just need basic, general properties of polynomials of even degree.

Comment: Because this polynomial is of even degree and has positive coefficient for the highest power of the variable, $x$. It will have a global minimum. Since it is degree 4, there my also be another local minima which is not necessarily as low as the global minimum.

Comment: "Zero isn't an option, because I've done the rational root theorem and found all possible roots."  Is it possible for a 4th degree equation to have irrational roots?  My first try, which might not be very helpful would be to try to examine the first and second derivatives of the function, so that I could scrutinize the behavior of the function.  While the 2nd derivative would be a 2nd degree polynomial, the first derivative would be the more difficult 3rd degree polynomial.  ...see next comment

Comment: If finding the zeroes of the first derivative (i.e. the 3rd degree polynomial) proves too onerous, I would instead spot check values of the first derivative at various points, and also be guided by knowledge of the second derivative.  At this point, absent some elegant shortcut, it becomes a matter of simple intellectual *ditch-digging*.

Comment: For odd degree polynomials, no.  For even degree ones, finding a lower bound shouldn't be very difficult (in the case mentioned, completing the squares gives you one easily enough.); however if you want the minimum/ best lower bound, you will need to find the roots of the derivative.

Comment: @user2661923 It's for a project, and the roots are required to be real, negative, and rational.

Comment: Also, I figured it out.. -3 is a lower bound. sorry for bothering

Answer (score 0):

A fairly standard method for finding extrema of a function is known as the first derivative test. Applying this to the given quartic equation yields:

$f'(x)=280x^3+489x^2+218x+37$

Since $37$ is prime, it is unlikely that this factors nicely. Using a graphing calculator app I found that it has 1 real solution at $x\approx -1.183$. This corresponds to the global minimum of the original function, as can readily be verified with a graph. Acquiring an explicit solution for the minimum would require Cardano's method to solve $f'(x)=0$ explicitly. Followed by a very messy calculation with the original quartic to obtain the exact $y$-coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial has two negative roots, $-\frac{3}{2}$ and $-\frac{2}{5}$. There are no positive roots according to the Descartes rule of signs. The polynomial is of even degree with a positive leading coefficient so it goes to positive infinity as $x$ tends to infinity. Thus, there should be a lower bound for some $x \in (-\frac{3}{2},-\frac{2}{5})$.

Comment: ??? Saying $B$ is a lower bound says that $B\le p(x)$ for every $x$. Saying there should be a lower bound between $-3/2$ and $-2/5$ says that in addition $-3/2\le B\le -2/5$. Surely you didn't mean that...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: certainly, I should have been more clearly that the interval is for the values of $x$. Let me correct this.